# Insert unicode string to SQL Server using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, unicode

I have created a stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spIns_nav_Content
  @CategoryID nVarChar(50),
  @ContentText nVarChar(Max)
AS
  INSERT INTO dbo.nav_Content(CategoryID, ContentText, Active)
  VALUES (@CategoryID, @ContentText, 1)
```

In my ASP.net application I have a textbox and a button. My aspx page looks like this:

```
<div>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Text here"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtContent" runat="server" Font-Names="ML-TTKarthika"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
  <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Font-Names="ML-TTKarthika"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

When clicked on `btnUpload` I need to save the non-English (Malayalam) text in `txtContent` to database as unicode characters. The click event is as follows:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestMalayalamConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
  con.Open();
  SqlCommand sqlCmd = con.CreateCommand();
  sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  sqlCmd.CommandText = "spIns_nav_Content";
  sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "Rashriyam";
  sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentText", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = txtContent.Text;
  sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
  con.Close();
  lblContent.Text = txtContent.Text;
}
```

When I see my db table the value in `ContentText` is in English. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the purpose of the font?

If it's mapping english characters to a foreign character set for display purposes (which as far as I can tell it does), then the DB is going to store english characters, as they are what is being typed in.

I typed `hello` into a font preview and could see that there were two characters the same for the letter `l`, then the `o`.

Effectively, all you are doing is substituting the typed english characters for the foreign character set at display time only. The underlying characters are still english.

To store Unicode characters, you'd have to actual enter unicode characters into the input control.